# Any objections to using /32 instead of common /24 netmask on a client?

Tags: networking, router, arp

For whatever reason ARP doesn't work properly on my network(separate problem, AP isolation turned off on router, really no idea). Then I discovered setting /32 netmask on client devices can let me communicate between clients through router which has proper ARP records.

Such as 192.168.100.5 to 192.168.100.6 through 192.168.100.1

My question is, is this "good" practice since all packages go through router/switch ANYWAY. No noticeable performance degradation since I know because this will NOT bypass router's CPU(or maybe ASIC) routing. When using /24 it will, in theory, bypass router's CPU, directly switch out.

FYI of course, my network is /24.

Comment: This os not a great idea.  Fix ypur network instead.

Comment: @davidgo reason? IP layer doesn't care MAC source.

Comment: Agreed that the IP layer does not care about MAC addresses, but if IP addresses are /32's then they can have no knowledge of any other hosts **including the gateway**   - I expect that this is working through some kind of quirk in the network stack(s) you are using and can't be relied upon, if indeed they are /32's.  I'd be curious to see your route table!

Comment: Or, why does ARP only works between the gateway and its "client" hosts?